# Qual o nome do recurso/termo que expande um trecho de código entre chaves?

Tags: ide

Qual o nome do recurso que expande um trecho de código entre chaves?

Estou programando um arquivo `.jsp` mas a `IDE` não identifica as chaves, assim não consigo contrair o código.

Comment: Não sei se o nome tem alguma relevância, mas ele costuma se chamar *expand code* :)

Comment: porque não consigo minimizar o código entende? talvez o recurso não esteja instalado para a linguagem

Comment: Para contrair é *fold*.

Comment: @durtto Qual a ide que você está usando?

Comment: Alternativamente, faz parte do "code folding"

Comment: Como que chama a IDE ?

Comment: @MarlonTiedt, independente de IDE, quero saber o nome do termo entende?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_folding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O nome deriva do nome da funcionalidade que fecha o código, só que o nome dessa funcionalidade varia de IDE para IDE. Alguns nomes que eu já vi são:

- Code Unfold, quando deriva de Code Folding.
- Code Expand, quando deriva de Code-Collapsing.